# SQL: Turning a single set of results into a table

Tags: t-sql

I've created a T-SQL query which counts all of the students who are at a lesson at specific times, for each day of the week (below).  Is there a way of taking this query(which gives a snapshot) and displaying results for a variety of different '@time' variables so I can get a table which looks something like:

```
Day 09:00  09:30..... etc
1   300    455
2   43     467
3   21     312
```

The increment in time along the columns would be constant - and ideally adjustable, but if that's needlessly complex, every 30 mins would probably be optimum.

Query:

```
DECLARE @time AS VARCHAR(5)

SELECT @time = '09:00'

SELECT A.day_of_week,
    A.Sum(count_student) AS Students
FROM (
        SELECT sttrgprf.register_id,
    sttrgprf.day_of_week,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), start_time, 108) AS start_time,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), end_time, 108) AS end_time,
    Count(DISTINCT Student_ID) AS count_student
FROM qlsdat.dbo.Stthstud
    INNER JOIN qlsdat.dbo.Sttrgprf AS Sttrgprf
        ON Stthstud.register_id = Sttrgprf.register_ID
            AND Stthstud.register_group = Sttrgprf.register_group
            AND Stthstud.acad_period = Sttrgprf.acad_period
WHERE sttrgprf.Acad_period = ''14/15''
GROUP BY sttrgprf.register_id,
    sttrgprf.day_of_week,
    sttrgprf.start_time,
    sttrgprf.end_time
    ) AS A
WHERE Start_time <= @time
    AND End_time > @time
GROUP BY day_of_week
ORDER BY day_of_week
```

Comment: Yes, you need a dynamic query, even if you use the PIVOT operator. You'd need to add a little more info on what you want to achieve to be able to help you: possible values of time (fixed or a different one each time?), real `STATEMENT`...

Comment: Edited to include the information you asked for.

Comment: Which kind of data are in start_time, end_time and day_od_week?

Comment: start_time & end_time are datetime fields, with no date information, day_of_week is a numeric field 1 - 6 (no classes on sunday (7))

Comment: To add some other context, sttrgprf contains information about start and end times of registers, and stthstud contains information about students on registers.